# Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have just installed Android Studio. And I have this problem. [Here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX7zv.png)
then I clicked the link and downloaded the zip file manually. Then I installed it. Now, when I type Gradle -v on Command-Line, it shows that everything is fine with Gradle. [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PETiT.png).
Android Gradle Plugin version is 3.6.3 [Here is Android Gradle Plugin Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgSlY.png)
This is the information about the Android Studio that I am using: Android Studio 4.1.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 4, 2020

Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64

VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 10.0

GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep

Memory: 1237M

Cores: 8

Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true,
external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Comment: What version of gradle plugin you are using ? Add it with question . It will be in project level gradle file

Comment: Please avoid screenshots for one line error messages. You could simply wirte that you got this error: "Coudl not install Gradle distribution ...". Also a Screenshot showing everyhing is fine does not transport valuable information. To improve your questions, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a Compatibility issue because you are using a old plugin version with latest `Gradle version` .

Change plugin version in Project level gradle .

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

Then try to build your project . Check the Compatible version in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)